# PhantomJS not evaluating new content

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, ecmascript-6

I am writing a script using the [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) package to retrieve the contents of a shoutbox on a webpage that is refreshed using AJAX requests every second or so. I open the page, inject jQuery, and evaluate (using `page.evaluate`) by using jQuery to fetch the contents of that shoutbox and return the messages to the phantom instance. Currently, my script is only able to print the first 30 or so messages then it does not find any new messages even though there really are.

**tl;dr: The jQuery code keeps returning the same messages even though new ones have appeared on the page.**

Here's the stripped-down code (no error checking or logging messages):

```
'use strict';
let phantom = require('phantom');

function isShoutboxVisible() {
  return $('#shoutbox_frame').is(':visible');
}

function listenForShoutbox(page) {
  setInterval(() => {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      // Return the shoutbox responses and slice off the notice.
      var $shouts = $('#shoutbox_frame .smallfont').slice(1);
      var buffer = [];
      $shouts.each(function() {
        buffer.push($(this).context.innerText.trim());
      });
      return buffer;
    }).then((buffer) => {
      // Print shoutbox messages...
      // `buffer` doesn't seem to change after first evaluation.
    });
  }, 1000);
}

phantom.create().then((ph) => {
  // See: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js
  function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    let maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 1000;
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    let condition = false;
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition) {
        condition = testFx();
      } else {
        if (!condition) {
          ph.exit(3);
        } else {
          onReady();
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    }, 250);
  }

  ph.createPage().then((page) => {
    let res = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      page.open(SITE_URL).then((status) => {
        status === 'success' ? resolve() : reject();
      });
    });
    res.then(() => {
      page.includeJs(JQUERY_URL).then(() => {
        // Wait for the DOM to render the shoutbox.
        waitFor(
          () => page.evaluate(isShoutboxVisible),
          () => {
            listenForShoutbox(page);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I don't understand why this fails to work. It's to my understanding that PhantomJS executes AJAX calls so the shoutbox should be routinely updated. Is there a problem with the way I do asynchronous work? Perhaps I need to reload the page each time?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Rewriting the script from ES6 to ES5 then running directly from `phantomjs` seems to be working.

Comment: Make a screenshot to see if there really are new messages. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-3_phantomnodeerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added all those listeners and got some messages back but nothing indicating an error. I took screenshots every 3 seconds and it appears the shoutbox isn't being updated for some reason.

Comment: PhantomJS version 2.1.1.